# Ubuntu 20.04 refuses to start GUI on boot

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, gui

I am unable to get my dualbooting Ubuntu 20.04 and Windows 10 machine to boot to Ubuntu. It will idle forever with one line of text on-screen reading `/dev/nvme0n1p5: clean, 807036/5259264 files, 12182267/21035520 blocks`.

I am able to go to a terminal by doing ctrl+alt+f2.

I have currently tried uninstalling and reinstalling my graphics drivers via

`sudo apt-get purge nvidia*`

`sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`

(Before this issue, I  had used nVidia's driver, specifically `nvidia-driver-440`)

My graphics card is a GeForce GTX 1660Ti.

Comment: It appears to me to be hanging on a hard drive/ssd block or partition.  This could be a hardware failure or fstab error.

Comment: I have given up at this point; I'm just reinstalling Ubuntu. Nothing on my SSD seems out the ordinary in terms of failure.